# Can't attach EBS volume to statefulset pod. Wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/XXX, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, storage, amazon-eks

Error:

```
  Warning  FailedMount             108s                kubelet                  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[nexus], unattached volumes=[nexus kube-api-access-4p4gw nexus-pvc]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount             76s (x18 over 21m)  kubelet                  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "nexus" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = could not format "/dev/nvme1n1" and mount it at "/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/nexus/globalmount": mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t xfs -o nouuid,defaults /dev/nvme1n1 /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/nexus/globalmount
Output: mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/nexus/globalmount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

My resources in K8s:
PVC:

```
$ kubectl describe pvc -n nexus nexus
Name:          nexus
Namespace:     nexus
StorageClass:  io2
Status:        Bound
Volume:        nexus
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      10000Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       nexus-0
Events:        <none>
```

PV:

```
kubectl describe pv nexus
Name:            nexus
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection external-attacher/ebs-csi-aws-com]
StorageClass:    io2
Status:          Bound
Claim:           nexus/nexus
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        10000Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:              CSI (a Container Storage Interface (CSI) volume source)
    Driver:            ebs.csi.aws.com
    FSType:            xfs
    VolumeHandle:      vol-XXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ReadOnly:          false
    VolumeAttributes:  <none>
Events:                <none>
```

Statefulset volume sections:

```
      volumes:
      - name: nexus
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nexus
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: nexus-pvc
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20Gi
      storageClassName: aws-efs
      volumeMode: Filesystem



        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /nexus-data-efs
          name: nexus-pvc
        - mountPath: /nexus-data
          name: nexus
```

It's worth to mention that everything is working as expected when I am deleting EBS volume and keep EFS.

Also:

- I can attach volume on basic ec2 instance, but I am also getting this error:
  wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
  but this option: "-o nouuid" solves the issue.
- I am able to mount efs to statefulset
- EBS was created manually, formated to xfs type so it's not a problem with ext4 filesystem type.
  **file -s on mounted EBS shows: "SGI XFS"**
- I am using ebs csi driver
- I added IAM Role to nodes (EBS CSI Driver Role)
- EKS version 1.21

Answer (score 0):

If the `Statefulset` snippet is complete, I am wondering why it is missing volumeClaimTemplates for ebs

Also, based on the output of the Persistent Volume (PV) description, it appears that the `PV` with the name `nexus` was automatically provisioned, not manually provisioned.

I think The PV specifies the `io2` StorageClass, which indicates that the volume is `dynamically` provisioned using the EBS io2 StorageClass. Dynamic provisioning means that the PV was automatically created when a `Persistent Volume Claim (PVC)` was requested, and it matched the criteria defined in the StorageClass.

Can you please list the Persistent Volumes in the nexus namespace to verify

If you want to use a manually created EBS (Elastic Block Store) volume in a StatefulSet in Kubernetes, you need to follow these steps:

- You should create a Persistent Volume (PV) and specify the `volumeID`
- Create a Persistent Volume Claim (PVC) that will request the specific PV you created in the previous step.
- Attach PVC to the StatefulSe: specify the created PVC in the volumeClaimTemplates section. Make sure to use the correct PVC name that you created in the previous step.